# Angular ngrx example understanding reselect

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I go over the [ngrx/example](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/) repo, and I don't understand the usage of `reselect`.

For my understanding, the `createSelector` function takes two functions that accept the same parameter.

For example:

```
const shopItemsSelector = state => state.shop.items
const taxPercentSelector = state => state.shop.taxPercent

const taxSelector = createSelector(
  subtotalSelector,
  taxPercentSelector,
  (subtotal, taxPercent) => subtotal * (taxPercent / 100)
)
```

Both the functions are taking the **whole** state as a parameter.

But in the ngrx example -

```
export const getLayoutState = (state: State) => state.layout;
export const getShowSidenav = (state: State) => state.showSidenav;
export const getShowSidenav = createSelector(getLayoutState, fromLayout.getShowSidenav);

store.select(fromRoot.getShowSidenav)
```

It seems that in the above example they are taking different params, the first takes the whole state and the second the layout state.

How it's working?

Comment: Take a look into this [**demo app**](https://github.com/aravindfz/ngrx-store-demo) which says the best way of creating and managind states

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is confusing because it is spread out over multiple files.

Inside of the layout.ts we have:

```
export const getShowSidenav = (state: State) => state.showSidenav;
```

Then inside of the index.ts we have:

```
export const getLayoutState = (state: State) => state.layout;
export const getShowSidenav = createSelector(getLayoutState, 
   fromLayout.getShowSidenav);
```

So if we were to just do it all in one file it would look like this:

```
// getLayoutState works at the AppState level
export const getLayoutState = (state: State) => state.layout;

export const getShowSidenav = createSelector(getLayoutState, 
   // This fat arrow function operates only on what getLayoutState gives us
   (layoutState: LayoutState) => layoutState.showSidenav);
```

In this example when you use createSelector the first parameter takes getLayoutState which returns the layout slice from the whole AppState.  Then that value is sent to the createSelector's final parameter.

Here's a further breakdown of what I mean by final parameter:

```
// getA values are passed to the final function as a
export const getSomething = createSelector(getA, 
   (a) => a);

// getA, getB values are passed to the final function as a, b
export const getSomething = createSelector(getA, getB, 
   (a, b) => a + b);

// getA, getB, getC values are passed to the final function as a, b, c
export const getSomething = createSelector(getA, getB, getC 
   (a, b, c) => a + b + c);
```

In all of these cases the final parameter which is always a function takes as parameters all of the previous selectors.

Comment: But that's not how the example from reselect works. In the example, the second parameter does not get the result of the first one.

Comment: From their docs (https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#createselectorinputselectors--inputselectors-resultfunc) it says:

createSelector(...inputSelectors | [inputSelectors], resultFunc)

Takes one or more selectors, or an array of selectors, computes their values and passes them as arguments to resultFunc.

In other words the first set of selectors passes their value to resultFunc which is the last parameter.  In this case getLayoutState is an inputSelector and the last fat arrow function is the resultFunc.